# Calling extension or module method from plugin

Tags: module, plugin, extension

I need to call an extension or module method from a plugin.

Anyone know how to do that?

Eventually solved with this code:

```
include_once(PATH_THIRD.'extension/mod.extension.php');
$this->EE->load->add_package_path(PATH_THIRD.'extension/'); 
$ext = new Extensionclass();
$PI = $ext->extension_function($params);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with the following example code within your plugin:

```
require_once PATH_THIRD."modulename/modulefilename";
$obj = new ModuleClass();
$obj->module_method();
```

Hope, it would help you.

Comment: Similar to how I eventually figure it out. Thanks.